# Why does this function not return the correct conditional result?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple conditional within a function to test my function skills. (I know that it doesn't need to be in a function but I'm exploring).

However, I cannot work out why this function is not returning the correct conditional output?

When I enter anything other than '42' or 'forty-two' or 'forty two' it still responds with "Yes".

```
def meaning_of_life():
    meaning = ponder(input("What is the Answer to the Great Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything? "))
    print(ponder(meaning))

def ponder(meaning):
    if meaning == "42":
        return "Yes"
    elif meaning == "forty-two" or "forty two":
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"


meaning_of_life()
```

Comment: The condition `or "forty two"` is always `True`.

Comment: `elif meaning == "forty-two" or "forty two":` is two separate conditions here - it's true either `if meaning == "forty-two"` OR `if "forty two"` - and `if` on a non-empty string is always true.

Comment: Your second if condition will always return true . The second part in or "forty two" will always be true

Comment: Wondering about the recursion `meaning = ponder(answer); ponder(meaning)`: Given correct `ponder()` and I answer "forty-two" the meaning becomes 'Yes' and is pondered-upon again to print `No`. Is this logic intended?

Comment: @hc_dev This is the issue! Thank you! Could you add this to your answer and I will accept this!

Should be your solution plus:
print(meaning) not print(ponder(meaning))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue: `or True`

The evaluation of your `elif` condition is as follows:

1. `meaning == "forty-two"` is `False` for any non-match
2. the next part after `or` is `True` because a non-empty string like `"forty two"` is `True` (we call it *truthy*)

The order of evaluation is controlled by *operator precedence*.

In that case the conditional evaluates to `False or True` which is finally always `True`. Even with other cases as non-match the last `or True` will guarantee that the `elif` branch if reached will always be `True`.

#### Test boolean evaluation of conditions

You can test it in Python REPL:

```
>>> meaning = 'nothing'
>>> meaning == "forty-two" or "forty two"
'forty two'
>>> bool(meaning == "forty-two" or "forty two")
True
```

Or when using your script, add debug-prints:

```
print(meaning == "forty-two" or "forty two")
print(bool(meaning == "forty-two" or "forty two"))
```

### Fix the boolean logic

to have each equals condition separate:

```
elif meaning == "forty-two" or meaning == "forty two"
```

See also: [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

#### Simplification

The conditional (if-statement) to test for multiple cases can be simplified using the `in` operator against a tuple, set or list:

```
    if meaning in ("42", "forty-two", "forty two"):
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"
```

or as **pattern to map a value** even shorter:

```
return "Yes" if meaning in ("42", "forty-two", "forty two") else "No"
```

Try it in the REPL:

```
>>> meaning = 'nothing'
>>> "Yes" if meaning in ("42", "forty-two", "forty two") else "No"
'No'
```

and test a negative-case (string `'42'`) plus the edge-case (number `42` as int):

```
>>> meaning = "42"
>>> "Yes" if meaning in ("42", "forty-two", "forty two") else "No"
'Yes'
>>> meaning = 42
>>> "Yes" if meaning in ("42", "forty-two", "forty two") else "No"
'No'
```

### Still issues with `meaning_of_life()`?

Explained a potential logical bug with my comments:

```
def meaning_of_life():
    meaning = ponder(input("What is the Answer to the Great Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything? "))
    # Warning:  meaning was already pondered upon! So meaning is either 'Yes' or 'No' 
    # Still want to ponder again on `Yes` or `No` ?
    print(ponder(meaning))  # ponder on the pondered meaning and print the result 

def ponder(meaning):
    # print(type(meaning))
    return 'Yes' if str(meaning) in ('42', 'forty-two', 'forty two') else 'No'

meaning_of_life()
```

See the two invocations of `ponder`:

```
meaning = ponder( .. )
.. ponder(meaning) ..
```

Is same as `ponder(ponder( .. )))` (we call this *recursion*)

#### Fix `meaning_of_life()`

To:

```
def meaning_of_life():
    answer = input("What is the Answer to the Great Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything? ")
    print(ponder(answer))  # ponder on the answer and print the result
```

Comment: Really helpful thank you. However, there is a new problem as now everything is returning "No". All I did was replace the conditionals with your shortest recommendation: return "Yes" if meaning in ("42", "forty-two", "forty two") else "No"

Comment: @SentBackInTime Thanks! I added further test-cases, so you can see what happens on numbers as input ️ See the docs for `input` (depending on your Python version, it may return a string or a number for plain `42` entered). Defensive and if `print(type(meaning))` gives any other than `str` would be converting to string before comparing strings - e.g. `str(meaning) in ('42', 'forty-two', 'forty two')`

Comment: It returns a string so I don't need to convert it but still can't work out why everything now returns "No"? I have gone down a rabbit hole with this one.

Comment: @SentBackInTime Ponder over it as often and long as you want ️ But just call the method `ponder` once. See my last update.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
elif meaning == "forty-two" or "forty two":
```

to this:

```
elif meaning == "forty-two" or meaning == "forty two":
```